# can't get a query response into an array of strings and back to my javascript

Tags: php, ajax, arrays

This seems simple, but I'm so new to this that I can't get it running - even after hours of reading tutorials and examples. I want my PHP to run a query, make an array of strings, and return the array to the jQuery ajax() that called for the data. The return array should be the strings stored in the database, and look like

```
citiesWithBoroughs = [
    "Dallas, Dallas County, Texas, United States",
    "Fort Worth, Tarrant County, Texas, United States",
    "El Paso, El Paso County, Texas, United States"
];
```

The query and array creation code are below. The query works in MySQL Workbench and returns the data I want. I have hard coded the country and state below to reduce sources of error while testing. I will replace them with "mysql_real_escape_string($countryAbbreviation)", and so forth, when I get a controlled test working.

```
$return_arr=array();

$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT cityWithBoroughsGeonamed FROM places.boroughs
    WHERE countryAbbreviation='US'
    AND stateProvinceAbbreviation='NY'
    ") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch)){
    $return_arr[]=$row['cityWithBoroughsGeonamed'];
}
echo $return_arr;
```

Currently, Firebug tells me the key/value data goes to the PHP server, but I get an empty array returned.  I've tried several things, but get nothing or an empty array - after lots of trials.

On the JavaScript side, here is the ajax function that requests the data, and gets the returned array.

```
citiesWithBoroughs = function (request, response){
$.ajax({
    url: "getCitiesWithBoroughs.php",
    data: {stateProvinceAbbreviation: $("#hiddenState").val(),
        countryAbbreviation: $('input[name=country]:checked').val()},
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (data){
        response;
    }
});
```

What has to change to get this right? Please be specific about code. I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: If you get an empty array from php, perhaps there was an empty result in the sql query.  Can you verify that the sql query works and returns some rows through phpmyadmin or another mysql tool?

Comment: My second paragraph above says that the query has been tested and works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

echo will output a string. $return_arr is an array of strings and `echo $return_arr;` will only output `Array()`. I would recommend using `echo json_encode($return_arr);` and handling the json encoded string in the success callback in the client side script.

Comment: Yes, Firebug says that Array() is passed, but it has no content.  Are you saying that PHP has no command to pass an array with string contents?  I have used json_encode() in other situations, but I thought an array of strings would be simpler in this case.

Comment: PHP won't automatically transform an array of strings into the exact output format you want, that's why you need to enclose the array variable with the json_encode() function.

Comment: Thanks, I have data passing, and learned that JSON is the only way to do it, even when a simpler data format would be OK.